# Update the domain name of all URL in a page on PHP site

Tags: php, url

I have a page located `http://www.example.com/product/`. It has hundreds of products in the listing. Each product has a URL and it is linked to the detailed page accordingly. I want to bulk update the domain name of these link.

For example, in the product list, I have:

- `http://www.example.com/htc/desire`
- `http://www.example.com/htc/widlfire`
- `http://www.example.com/motorola/atrix`
- ...

I want to change them to:

- `http://www.another-server.com/htc/desire`
- `http://www.another-server.com/htc/widlfire`
- `http://www.another-server.com/motorola/atrix`
- ...

***Note:** The links are dynamically generated by PHP, not hardcoded.*

How can I bulk update the domain name of these links?

Answer (score 0):

A simple [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)?

```
$var = 'http://www.example.com/motorola/atrix';
$new = str_replace('example.com', 'anothers-erver.com', $var);
echo $new; //http://www.anothers-erver.com/motorola/atrix
```

Comment: Sorry for misleading, the link is dynamically generated by PHP, not hardcode link.

Comment: ...and? just pass the variable that contains the link into the `str_replace` function. Maybe post some code so I can do the *whole* thing for you.

Comment: But how can I retrieve all link in the page? I don't want to update the link one by one. Thanks

Comment: Without you posting some sort of code, I don't think I can make my answer any clearer.. maybe take a look at this link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/getting-started.php

Answer (score -2):

"Replace all" in notepad might do the trick, dont you think?

Comment: "Sorry for misleading, the link is dynamically generated by PHP, not hardcoded link" well then depends on how it is generated and you gotta change it there i guess...